# Admob September 14th Match Rate Plummet

Tags: admob

We have a product that for the past year has had a match rate on iOS 80%+ android 70%+. On September 14th it dropped to less than 1%. We have Facebook Audience network as well as Ad Colony both bidding mediation partners. Across the board, even the mediation has had no matches either via AdMob mediation.

We have made sure that the AdMob SDK is the latest. I have tried to create a new placement id that is not mediated and it returns `No ad to show'. Also using the demo placement ids successfully display the AdMob demo ads.

Any insight would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a site for discussion of features or usage of the AdMob service.

Comment: Fair, enough. Its not so much a feature request.  I am curious if something has happened outside of updating the SDKs . Or if any one else has seen this drop.